# How do I find the controls after adding in an object?

Tags: interface

Where else can I find this after adding in an object?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you add an object in the 3d-view, the creation variables (which you are searching for) are still accessable and editing them can be done. After any modification in the 3d-view (such as selecting another object) the creation variables can no longer be accessed, you have commited to the creation values. Use regular editing for changing the mesh, or create a new object until you're satisfied.